# PHP return rows with similar values - have to matched first word

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

```
$companies = array(
  array('id' => '1','name' => 'Fifo Limited'),
  array('id' => '2','name' => 'FIFO Ltd'),
  array('id' => '3','name' => 'BitBytes Ltd'),
  array('id' => '4','name' => 'Info Sys'),
  array('id' => '5','name' => 'DevSquad'),
  array('id' => '6','name' => 'IT Magnet'),
  array('id' => '7','name' => 'Fifo-IT'),
  array('id' => '8','name' => 'Others')
);
```

I need rows with similar values - where names are matches on `30+ percentages`.
Here expected rows to be returned with `ID = 1, 2, 7` because they're contains similar name `'fifo'`.

I'm looking for solution with PHP or Javascript, also SQL if possible.

Comment: What if an array has more than two words are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function getSimilarities($data, $pers){

   $result = [];
   $tmp = [];        

   foreach($data as $ind => &$record){
        // split string by special chars '-' or ' ', array
        $name = preg_split('/[- ]/',$record['name']);                       

        // makes first word to lowercase
        $record['lowercase'] = strtolower($name[0]);                        

        // first word length
        $record['strlength_first'] = strlen($record['lowercase']);          

        // string length 
        $record['strlength_full'] = strlen($record['name']);                

        // if length > 0
        if ($record['strlength_full'] &&                                   
        // and if length of forst word >= 30% string length
           $record['strlength_first']/$record['strlength_full'] >= $pers){  

            $input = preg_quote($record['lowercase'], '~'); 

            if(preg_grep('~'.$input.'~', $record)) 
            $tmp[$record['lowercase']][] = $record['id'];    
       }         
   }

    // if more than 1 = similar names    
    foreach($tmp as $key=>$matches){                                     
        if (count($matches)>1){
            $result[$key] = $matches;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$percentage = 0.3;

print_r(getSimilarities($companies, $percentage));
```

Will produce output like:

```
Array
(
    [fifo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 7
        )

)
```

You can modify your input data and change percentage.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2FOLZ)**

Comment: @AtiarRahman, you're welcome! If you wanna retrieve data records you can use [this code](https://3v4l.org/htFk9)

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_quote` and `preg_grep` for this.

```
<?php
$input_value = 'Fifo';
$input = preg_quote($input_value, '~');
$companies = array(
  array('id' => '1','name' => 'Fifo Limited'),
  array('id' => '2','name' => 'FIFO Ltd'),
  array('id' => '3','name' => 'BitBytes Ltd'),
  array('id' => '4','name' => 'Info Sys'),
  array('id' => '5','name' => 'DevSquad'),
  array('id' => '6','name' => 'IT Magnet'),
  array('id' => '7','name' => 'Fifo-IT'),
  array('id' => '8','name' => 'Others')
);
$ids = array();
foreach($companies as $value){
  $value['name']= strtolower($value['name']);
  if(preg_grep('~' . strtolower($input) . '~', $value)){
    $ids[] = $value['id'];

  }
}
print_r($ids); exit;
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 7
)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Data are not fixed - so we can't use "Fifo" preg_quote('Fifo', '~'); as reference.

Comment: Yes, so here you can pass value dynamically as your requirement. like use $input_value = 'Info' and use preg_quote($input_value, '~'); so you got id 4 as per input_value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use PHP built-in [similar_text](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function:

```
$companies = array(
  array('id' => '1','name' => 'Fifo Limited'),
  array('id' => '2','name' => 'FIFO Ltd'),
  array('id' => '3','name' => 'BitBytes Ltd'),
  array('id' => '4','name' => 'Info Sys'),
  array('id' => '5','name' => 'DevSquad'),
  array('id' => '6','name' => 'IT Magnet'),
  array('id' => '7','name' => 'Fifo-IT'),
  array('id' => '8','name' => 'Others')
);

$skips = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($companies) - 1; ++$i) {
    for ($j = $i; $j < count($companies); ++$j) {
        if (in_array($companies[$j]['id'], $skips)) {
            continue;
        }

        similar_text($companies[$i]['name'], $companies[$j]['name'], $perc);
        if ($perc >= 30) {
            $results[$companies[$i]['id']][$companies[$j]['id']] = $companies[$j]['id'];
            $skips[] = $companies[$j]['id'];
        }
    }
}

$results = array_filter($results, function($result) {
   return count($result) > 1; 
});

print_r($results);
```

[Code snippet with example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be40757a52db3f63c93becc8f05cb71bb1aa4ce5)

Comment: Your snippet produces wrong output. OP desired other one.